# gridview with different data sources in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datasource

Is it possible to bind columns of gridview with different data sources ?
I have two different datasources in my web.config file and i want to select data in one gridview with different datasources .

how can i fill my dataset or datatable for the gridview ?

Comment: Can you please try something and comeback with code and details what problem are you facing?

Comment: ask about code errors here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think from what you asked
the best way is to merge both in one dataset or datatable then fill the gridview with this new combined object

Note: for very high speed use special objects you develop to catch data and return the number of rows so you do not make it very slow using List grow process

**Better Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NewTable](
    [id]            [smallint] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name]          [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
);
CREATE Procedure NewTableGetAll
BEGIN
    SELECT      Count(id) as RowsCount
    FROM        NewTable

    SELECT      * 
    FROM        NewTable
END


public class NewTable
{
    private short _id;

    private string _name;

    public short Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public void Fill(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        _id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["id"]);
        _name = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
    }
}


Public static class SNewTable{
    Public List<NewTable> GetNewTable(*****************){
        ****************
        ****************
        List<NewTable> myList = null;
        If(reader.Read()){
            myList = new List<NewTable>(Convert.ToInt(reader[“RowsCount”]));
        }

        reader.NextResult();

        while(reader.Read()){
            NewTable obj = new NewTable();
            Obj.Fill(reader);
            myList.Add(obj);
        }

        ****************
        ****************
    }
}
```